# React native Animated example violating best practices?

Tags: react-native

As per best practices, component state is meant to be immutable. 
However, at least on the surface, the Animated class in react native seems to violate this requirement.

Should we set animated values outside of component state?

```
//from the example in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html
componentDidMount() {

   //look ma, you're changing a stateful value directly!
   this.state.bounceValue.setValue(1.5);

   //not sure how this works under the hood, but it looks to be doing the same thing
   Animated.spring(this.state.bounceValue, {
    toValue: 0.8,
    friction: 1,
   }).start()      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the document you mentioned, I found this useful sentence-

> This is done in an optimized way that is faster than calling `setState`
>   and re-rendering. Because the entire configuration is declarative, we
>   will be able to implement further optimizations that serialize the
>   configuration and runs the animation on a high-priority thread.

I hope this satisfies your query!